# Looking for Exactness in a set python

Tags: python, set

I'm looking to create a program that I will want to do more or less the following:

1. Read in a list of University names from multiple CSV files
2. Check if we have already stored the name (i.e. is it unique)
3. If it is already stored, move on, otherwise append it to a list

What I want is a list of all the UNIQUE University names we have so far (at this point, abbreviations do not matter to me), but the list of TOTAL names is quite large. Since python sets have very quick lookup times, I was thinking of first checking if the name is in the set, and if it isn't, append the name to both the unique list and the set (I need a list here as well because order matters). When you check if something is "in" a set, is that "in" command the same as if you check if a string of characters is within a larger string? In other words, with string comparison "University of Alabama" in "University of Alabama - Birmingham" returns True. In set comparison, will it return true if I test to see if "University of Alabama" is in the set, but ONLY "University of Alabama - Birmingham" has been added? If so, is there a way to test if the EXACT string "University of Alabama" has been added rather than other strings that contain "University of Alabama"?

Comment: `set` doesn't behave like `str` - it behaves like a list when using the `in` comparison i.e. it will work only with exact matches, no substrings/sublists.

Comment: I'm wondering why you don't use `OrderedDict` ? Also, if you're so sceptic why not comparing strings by their id ?

Answer (score 2):

To address your first issue, you can take a look at `OrderedSet`. There is a [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/)  for this which is referred to from the [Python 2 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html). This runs on Py2.6 or later and 3.0 or later without any modifications. The interface is almost exactly the same as a normal set, except that initialisation should be done with a list.

```
>>> s = OrderedSet([1, 2, 3])
>>> s.add(4)
```

Use this recipe at your own risk.

Next, `in` tests for exactness inside a set.

Observe:

```
>>> s = set(['hello'])
>>> 'he' in s
False
>>> s.add('he')
>>> 'he' in s
True
```

In other words, the search term must be present exactly (python will hash the string to determine if it exists or not, so partial strings will *not* match).

The same applies with `OrderedSet`.

Comment: This OrderedSet recipe doesn't extend the built-in `set`, and it seems like a lot of unnecessary code and an additional license to potentially violate for very little gain. (Yes, it is possible to violate the MIT license.)

Comment: @user2357112 Can confirm. I assumed `MutableSet` extended `set`, but this told me otherwise: `>>> issubclass(MutableSet, set)` ... 
`False`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, I meant it as a suggestion to eliminate the extra "unique" list.

Comment: And it does, but at the cost of a lot of code you don't need and an extra licensing consideration. If you want to eliminate the work of maintaining consistency between the set and the list, `list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(names))` does that with only standard library tools.

Comment: @user2357112 I did consider ordered dict, but it seemed over kill considering only the keys needed storing, the values would be `None`. That... I believe, would've been ugly.

Answer (score 0):

```
university_col = ...
universities = set()
for row in csv_reader:
    universities.add(row[university_col])

result = set()
base_name = ''
for university_name in sorted(universities):
    if not base_name or base_name not in university_name:
         base_name = university_name
    result.add(base_name)
```